# Viewing XML as table (not in code format)

Tags: xml

I have a XML file which is very large and contain many sub-branching (a bit complex). Viewing it as XML in code form using notepad is very confusing. Is there any way for viewing it as a file (not its text, but its layout)? I have tried using excel, but the format that excel generated is not totally correct (In term of columns and rows). I also look into importing the XML file into SQL 2008 R2. But this would require a lot of time creating the table (As the XML file is very large).

Answer (score 0):

I tried using http://xmlgrid.net/ and found it to be very nice. It automate the branching nicely